# R tables::tabular() use of Format() to get rid of scientifc and round

Tags: r, formatting, tabular

I have a quick question. I am using tables::tabular() and have some summary statistics which are displayed in scientific e notation.

I found out that using `Format(scientific=FALSE) * mean()` in this context helps me to get rid of the scientific e notation in the means, and other summary statistics i present.

Now, I also want to round this number with the format `0.123456789` (most of the means are means of ratios between 0 and 1 but not all) to show the digits left and maximum 4 to the right of the comma i.e. `0.1234`. I tried simply putting the `digits=4` option into the Format and while it seems to work when alone in the `Format()` function, it doesn't somehow when I also have `scientific=FALSE` in there. **Rather, with `Format(scientific=FALSE, digit=1)`, I still get 5 digits to the right of the comma.**

Do you know what is happening and how i can fix it?

Highly appreciate your help,
cork

Comment: Could you include a reproducible example?

Answer (score 2):

Have you already tried to use a global statement at the beginning like this: `options("digits" = 4)`?

All the best,
Patrick

Comment: Hi Patrick, 
do you mean by global in the tabular function? I am quite a novice, so I don't fully understand what you mean. I guess I have to read up upon the functionality of options in functions again.

Comment: Write it  just before your regular R code in your script.

Comment: Thank you Patrick and user2554330 for your efforts, I switched to using table1 package which did what I originally sought out to do for me.